# Why findOne({ id }) is not working properly in mongoose 6.012

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose to find one user by its id but it is not working correctly. I tried several different approaches but only got the wrong results or errors.

Here is my code.

```
const { id } = req.params;
const user = await User.findOne({ id });
console.log(id);
console.log(user);
return res.redirect("back");
```

I tried following approaches

1 - `await User.findOne({ id });` returning first user no matter what is id.

```
target id: a8fc083f3f55494fa2cadf9
{
  _id: new ObjectId("618fb03e37876d1f0bccb945"),
  name: 'bohetefyhy',
  email: 'refo@mailinator.com',
  dataRealm: new ObjectId("618fb0119eefb1308fe65610"),
  role: 'user',
  createdAt: 2021-11-13T12:31:58.846Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-11-15T08:03:34.422Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

2 - `await User.findOne({ id: id });` returning same result as above (1).

3 - `await User.findOne({ _id: id });` giving error.

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "a8fc083f3f55494fa2cadf9" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"
at model.Query.exec (C:\Users\khan\Documents\Projects\030FL014_Windshield\app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4545:21)
at model.Query.Query.then (C:\Users\khan\Documents\Projects\030FL014_Windshield\app\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4644:15)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I also noticed that in the result there is a missing **id** field that mongoose adds. And for **_id** value is new **ObjectId("618fb03e37876d1f0bccb945"**) instade of simply **"618fb03e37876d1f0bccb945"**

I am using

"mongoose": "^6.0.12",

MongoDB 5.0.3 2008R2Plus SSL (64 bit)

> Ok, so I found the issue, there are only 23 characters in my object Id one is missing from start. but still why there is id field missing that mongoose add and why there _id is **new ObjectId("618fb03e37876d1f0bccb945"**) instead of simply **"618fb03e37876d1f0bccb945"** when I'm logging

Comment: what is the difference between the 1st and 2nd approaches you've tried ?

Comment: Ok, so I found the issue, there are only 23 characters in my id.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem, and this is how I solved to get the data for the Id I'm looking for.

```
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

const id = '61929f3efc232d63cd9dcb6b';

user.findOne({ _id: ObjectId(id) })
.then((result) => {
 console.log(result);
})
.catch((err) => {
 console.log(err);
});
```

This is the data that I have for users information

[Users information data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YR46.png)

The Output:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61929f3efc232d63cd9dcb6b"),
  name: 'Ibrahem',
  email: 'I-A-H@hotmail.com',
  age: 24,
  createdAt: 2021-11-15T17:56:14.089Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-11-15T17:56:14.089Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use mongodb version v6.0.0, and this works for me.

```
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema); 

const userID="123123123123";

User.findOne({ _id: userID }, function (err, foundItem) { 
      console.log("foundItem: "+foundItem);
    }
```

userID type: **String**

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same types of problem today and solved it by [community guideline](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/12325).

I Solved it with these simple code. Maybe you can try it too. Here I tried it with Email, you can try it with _id. I found both of them valid.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const userModel = require('../models/usermodel');

    router.post('/api/user/registration', async (req, res) => {
    const emailX = req.body.email;
    const emailExist = await userModel.findOne({'email': emailX }); // Finding the Email exist or not
    console.log(emailX, "Email Exist: =>", emailExist);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying by ID, use `findById` instead of `findOne` as the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.findOne()) suggests:

```js
const user = await User.findById(mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose's findById method casts the id parameter to the type of the model's _id field so that it can properly query for the matching doc.

Try also checking

```
if (id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
  // Yes, it's a valid ObjectId, proceed with `findById` call.
}
```

OR

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid('your id here');
```

Comment: But we can clearly see that id is valid in log. target id: a8fc083f3f55494fa2cadf

Comment: It's a string so it's not valid as an _id field type.

Comment: Ok, so I found the issue, there are only 23 characters in my id. I think mongoose auto-convert string to object id.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
await User.findOne({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope this will work:

```
const {id} = req.params

await User.findOne({_id: ObjectId(id)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start debugging the issue by adding the following piece of code and try to check if the mongoose query is passing all the parameters which you passed:

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

I also faced similar issue and I was able to resolve it by
updating the schema with _id like below:

```
_id:  mongoose.Types.ObjectId
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be work

```
const { id } = req.params;
const user = await User.findById({ _id: id });
```